# Testing Solana Programs

Tags: solana-program-test, solana-client-sdk

So I'm looking for a way to write solana smart contract test cases, which crates are used for doing so? Example test cases written in rust would be of great help! I can write smart contracts using rust (no anchor) and want to test them in a similar fashion as well.